# Distinguishability problem /

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to put 6 balls in 3 boxes if the balls are distinguishable but the boxes are not?

I'm not quite sure how to approach it, $\frac{3^6}{3!}$ is not an integer.  Thanks.

Comment: Your calculation is almost right. I've updated my hint to include a solution.

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be solved in general with [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). For more on general distribution problems see [here](http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~holzmann/notes/distributions.pdf).

In your case you will want to sum $S(6,1) + S(6,2) + S(6,3)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$\frac{3^6}{3!}$ would work if the contents of the three boxes were always distinguishable. There is a problem when two of the boxes are empty. In other words, there are three ways—not six—to put all the balls in one of the boxes.

---

**Solution:**

Since there are $3$ ways to put all the balls in one box, it follows that there are $3^n-3$ ways to put the balls in boxes where at most one of the boxes is empty. In this latter case, we can divide by 3! since the three boxes along with their contents are now distinguishable.

Counting these, then adding back the one way to put all the balls in one box, gives the following:

$$\frac{3^6-3}{3!} + 1 = 122.$$

So you were close! Incidentally, if you get into Sterling numbers of the second kind, $S(n,k)$, you can check that for all $n$, we indeed have $S(n,1)+S(n,2)+S(n,3) = \dfrac{3^n-3}{3!} + 1$.

Comment: but that's $3^5/2$ ways, as in $121 \frac{1}{2}$ ways of doing something, so surely it would not work... Like if everything was distinguishable surely it would be just $3^6$, the total number of functions from a set of size $6$ to a set of size $3$?

Comment: @snulty Not quite. I added a full solution.

Comment: that's pretty cool (+1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the best at combinatorics but here's a go. I think I remember problems like this in statistical mechanics. $B$ for box.

$B\mid\quad B\mid\quad B\mid \qquad ways$

---

$6\mid\quad 0\mid\quad 0\mid \qquad 1 \qquad$ all in one box.

---

$5\mid\quad 1\mid\quad 0\mid \qquad6\qquad$ one of the six on its own

---

$4\mid\quad 2\mid\quad 0\mid \qquad {6\choose2}\qquad$ choose two of the six for one box

---

$4\mid\quad 1\mid\quad 1\mid \qquad \frac{6*5}{2}\qquad$ pick one of the six, then one of the 5 and divide by 2 ways of doing this.

---

$3\mid\quad 3\mid\quad 0\mid \qquad \frac{1}{2}{6\choose3}\qquad$ six choose 3 but divide by two because the boxes are indistinguishable.

---

$3\mid\quad 2\mid\quad 1\mid \qquad 6*{5\choose2}\qquad$ pick one of the six then two of the five remaining

---

$2\mid\quad 2\mid\quad 2\mid \qquad \frac{1}{3!}{6\choose2}\cdot{4\choose2}\qquad$ two of the six, then two of the remaining four, and there are 6 ways these can be ordered so divide out by this.

---

Thanks to Ned and JMac31 for the help

Comment: This approach should work, but as you have it now you are over counting. For example the $6 \cdot 5$ over counts because it takes into account the order you place elements into the boxes.

Comment: @JMac31 yes you're right. good point, I didn't think that through enough. I will fix it

Comment: @JMac31 Does that remove the ordering problem?

Comment: Besides the 4-1-1, it seems like that over counts the 2-2-2 's since e.g. {ab}{cd}{ef} would be counted with {ab} chosen from 6 then {cd} from 4 and then also with {cd} chosen from 6 and {ab} chosen from 4, and more (not just double, I think).

Comment: So the 2-2-2 case should have 15 altogether: fix one ball A, there are five choices to go with it. Having done that, fix the alphabetically first ball X not used so far, then there are three choices to go with it, for 5 x 3 = 15.

Comment: @ned Ah right yes, I should divide out by the number of ways they can be ordered $3!$. The stirling numbers way looks more appealing at this point haha

Comment: Why divide by 2 in the 3-2-1 case? No over counting there when you just pick 1 from 6, then 2 from 5. But you want the 1/2 in the 3-3-0 case.

Comment: @ned Oh i see what you mean. As in there's overcounting when boxes have the same amount, I thought it was just the method of counting. I just didn't think it through enough. It's starting to make sense though thanks.